# i want two pass two context in index.html file

Tags: python, html, django

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse,redirect
from .models import *


# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    products=Product.objects.all()
    params={'product':products}

    categories=Category.objects.all()
    category={'category':categories}

    return render(request,'index.html',params,category)
```

i am creating an ecommerce website on django and i want to pass two context in index.html one is product and one is category but after doing this the index.html is not working

Comment: Is anything stopping you from combining these contexts into a single dict?

Comment: You don't want two contexts, you want one context that contains the values for the products and categories. Use only the parameter `params` and define it with `params={'product':products, 'category':categories}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can put two items inside a dictionary. Instead of

```
products=Product.objects.all()
params={'product':products}

categories=Category.objects.all()
category={'category':categories}
```

You can do this:

```
context = {'product': products, 'category': categories}
```

And then pass the context dict:

```
return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You merge the two dictionaries, so:

```
def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    params = {'product': products}

    categories = Category.objects.all()
    category = {'category': categories}

    return render(request, 'index.html', {**params, **category})
```